# horizontal scrollable list fully centered with dynamic width items

Tags: html, css, width, centering, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to make an horizontal list to be centered, with its items to be centered too regarding the main parent (the window, or body) ; and because i don't know what kind and how many items i will have generated into that list, i'd need the items to be dynamic in width and the list scrollable so i can browse over all of them.

My attempts so far are good, i'm getting either : a centered list with non-centered items of dynamic width ; and a fully centered scrollable list with fixed width items.

The core idea is basically achieved by using:

```
ul {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Then the centering is made by wrapping the `<ul>` into a `<div>`, and making the `<div>` scroll the `<ul>` instead of the `<ul>` scrolling the `<li>`. It allows to add % based margins to the `<ul>`

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul {
  margin: 0 50%;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

For items to be centered by width, the idea is to use `translateX(-50%)` with a little twist: as i don't want my list to have extra space at the end of the scrolling, I'm removing the last item from the flow by positioning it in absolute at the end ; that way, the `<ul>` width looks like the sum of the items width minus one item.

```
ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 50%;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: some_number;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

li:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
}
```

**But how to keep it that way without setting the width is a mystery to me.

Any ideas out there ?**

Here's my fiddle with some comments in the CSS section : https://jsfiddle.net/11gkrju0/

I'd like *not* to use javascript at all for that as it is only a matter of styling, but messing with the dom is a totally viable option.

Thanks all for reading,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it's a bit tricky. The resolved fiddle is here with comments which i'm gonna describe here too. https://jsfiddle.net/11gkrju0/7/

First thing to notice, i added a `vertical-align: top;` to my `<li>`s to make sure there's no vertical gap at some point.

**Then.**

Boundaries for a non centered list are easy to catch:

```
+-----+---+---------+
|  A  | B |    C    |
+-----+---+---------+
^                   ^
a                   b
```

For a centered list, they change a little bit :

```
+-----+---+---------+
|  A  | B |    C    |
+-----+---+---------+
^  ^           ^    ^
a  c           d    b
```

To make the scroll right, we need to change the width of the `<ul>` from A->B to C->D. As its width is dynamicly calculated by its children width, we need to alter the children.

We can see that only the first and last children are the ones to be altered. As the text defines the width of each children, we cannot change the width property, but we can divide by 2 some defined values much more easily : font-size, padding.

```
li {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0 50px;
}

li:first-child, li-last-child {
  font-size: 6px;
  padding: 0 25px;
}
```

Now the list may look more like

```
+---+---+-----+
| a | B |  c  |
+---+---+-----+
^  ^       ^  ^
a  c       d  b
```

But then the problem is that the text and padding are smaller now. What we can do is to proxy the real buttons into an `:after` with the little trade of adding a text attribute to the li to feed the `content` property.

```
<li text='A'>A</li>
<li text='B'>B</li>
<li text='C'>C</li>
```

With that in the DOM, we can write that kind of CSS to create fake buttons which looks just like the real one (not to mention, hide the real one...)

```
li {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}

li:after {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: attr(text);
  color: #000;
}
```

Almost there, almost there...

The first and last children have been altered, and so their pseudo-child too... Side effect is that the width will be calculated for a 6px font-size. So we need to set back the width to twice needed, and reset the font-size to prevent inheritance.

```
li:first-child:after, #d li:last-child:after {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 200%;
}
```

Finally (yay), we pad the first element to half of its width to prevent collision with the 2nd one.

```
li:first-child:after {
  left: -100%;
}
```

We could have used `transform: translateX(-50%);` as well, but we're already manipulating absolute values so there's no need to apply an other layer of calculation on that.

Hoping it'll help someone.